# Shrinking Cdrive for ubuntu

Tags: windows-7

I have win 7 professional installed on 300 GB hard-disk,now I want to install Ubuntu and make my system dual boot,when I have 196 GB free,when I run shrink it tells me the following, (all numbers in mb)

Total size before shrink 296025

Size of available shrink space 2190

Enter the amount of space to shrink 2190

Total size after shrink 293835

Does this mean Ubuntu partition will be 2 GB?

Can I proceed with the shrink?

Answer (score 1):

yes, you have 2 GB of unallocated space.Not enough for Ubuntu.

First it is best to shrink windows partitions from within windows. The disk manager in administrator utilities can do the job.

Windows places some files at the end of the partition. Try temporarily disabling swap, Fast boot, and hibernation. Then show hidden files in the root file system (c:). There should be two hidden files: `pagefile.sys` and `hiberfil.sys`. Delete them. This should give you more room to shrink. I recommend 50 GB for ubuntu. This gives room for installing software and personal data.

Note: For dual booting, it is recommended to leave Fast Start and hibernation disabled.

Comment: These numbers are provided by the disk manager of win7

Comment: ok, turn off swap, hibernation and Fast Start. and delete the associated files. this should give more room to shrink.

Comment: Pagefile.sys is missing in C

Comment: have yoou  tried shrinking again? Windows may have deleted pagefile.sys when you disabled swap.

Comment: Thanx friend,pagefile.sys and hyberfil.sys both missing in C